# AZEROTHCORE - ./bin/acore-docker-build script returns a "unable to find image 'acbuild:latest' locally

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm trying to set up AzerothCore with Docker.  I'm following the instructions here: http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker, and used the following command to clone the git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk.git
```

The git clones successfully, and I move the `dbc`, `maps`, `mmaps`, and `vmaps` folders into the `~/azerothcore-wotlk/` directory.

I run the `./bin/acore-docker-generate-etc` script sucessfully.

However when I run the `./bin/acore-docker-build` script I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists...
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 11min 29s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 12min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 13min 44s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install -y git cmake make gcc g++ clang libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libncurses-dev libace-6.* libace-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
Unable to find image 'acbuild:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for acbuild, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I've checked other questions here and the only responses I've seen say that this can be caused by a repack.  However, I'm using the actual repository from git.  Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicating, that `acbuild:latest` cannot be found is actually only a result of the previous error to build said image. The idea of the `acore-docker-build` is to build the docker image `acbuild:latest` so that it can be ran afterwards. The script does not verify that the generation of the image was successful and then tries to run it anyway.

Your actual error is in all of those lines:
`E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1h 13min 44s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.`

This seems to be a timezone/time setting issue and you can find many suggestions how to fix this in the following questions (second one specifically related to docker):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059217/getting-release-is-not-valid-yet-while-updating-ubuntu-docker-container

Comment: Changing the time to match NTP time worked!  Thanks!